# Safari and IPhone and HTML Select and jQuery Mobile -- Close the "custom select control" from javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

[Safari Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW17) says:

> If you use the select HTML element in your webpage, iOS displays a custom select control that
>   is optimized for selecting items in the list using a finger as the input device.

So that is the "custom select control" I am asking about (I would call it a "native" control) and there is a nice picture of it in the referenced page, including the "Previous", "Next" and "Done" buttons.

I have a select list:

```
<select id="selected_item_selector">
<option value="1">first item</option>
<option value="2">second item</option>
<option value="#">Add a new item</option>
<select>
```

and javascript that says:

```
$(function() {
    var sel = $('#selected_item_selector');
    sel.change(function(e) {
        var selectedItemForm = $('#select_item_form'),
            id = $(this).val(),
            href = '/add-item.html';
        if(id == '#') {
            document.location.href = href;

        }
        /* do something with the id */
    });
    if(sel.val() == '#') {
        /* never have the "add" option selected */
        sel.val(0);
    }
});
```

So everything works as expected, NO PROBLEMS WITH THE CODE!!!!

THIS IS THE PROBLEM: When the browser is navigated to the new page, the "custom select control" remains open suggesting actions that have no connection to the page that is now in the browser.

HERE IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE FOR A SOLUTION: Tell me how to close the "custom select control" (aka "native" control) from my javascript code when unloading the page or loading the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Removing focus from the `select` should do the trick:

`sel.blur();`

Comment: @user1964895 Excellent! I'm glad it worked. Please set this answer as your accepted answer by clicking the hollow checkmark.